# is the inner product of two functions an absolute value?

Tags: inner-products

My notes state that if we have two functions, $f$ and $g$, defined over the same domain, $\Omega $, then the inner product is the quantity:

$$ \langle{f,g}\rangle =\int_{\Omega}f(x)g(x)dx $$

One of the properties stated is that $ \langle{f,g}\rangle > 0$ for all non zero functions.  However, in my eyes if on function is continuously negative, then $\langle{f,g}\rangle<0$.  Please explain.

Comment: The property should be $\langle f,f\rangle > 0$ for all non-zero $f$. Both arguments of the inner product are the same in that property.

Comment: First... I think its a little sloppy to say "the" inner product; its better to say, this is "an" inner product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with $\langle f, g \rangle < 0$ , this is NOT an axiom.  The axiom says, $\langle f, f \rangle \ge 0$ with equality if and only if $f=0$.